# How to show only element of array in output

Tags: arrays, mongodb, project, subdocument

I have document like this. How to show only element of array in output.

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5effaa5662679b5af2c58829"),
 email: “email@example.com”,
 name: {given: “Jesse”, family: “Xiao”},
 age: 31,
 addresses: [{label: “home”,
              street: “101 Elm Street”,
              city: “Springfield”,
              state: “CA”,
              zip: “90000”,
              country: “US”},
             {label: “mom”,
              street: “555 Main Street”,
              city: “Jonestown”,
              province: “Ontario”,
              country: “CA”}]
}
```

my query

```
{ "$project": { _id : 0, "addresses.country": 1 }  }
```

desired output

```
"country": “...”
```

actual output

```
{ 
    "addresses" : [
        {
            "country" : "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$match` to match the country
- `$replaceRoot` to make it root

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$addresses" },
  { "$match": { "addresses.country": "CA" } },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$addresses" } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Vy7DXGxvAD)**

Comment: I should use $project. Is there a way? "CA" doesnt matter any country.

Comment: may I know the reason "I should use project. "

Answer (score 0):

short answer is you use exclusion. use field:0 to exclude. so after find statement you would add something like: `db.project.find({..}, {_id:0:,label:0,city:0..etc})`

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved

```
        { "$unwind" : "$addresses" },
        {
            "$project" : {
                _id:0.0,
                "addresses" : "$addresses._id"
            }
        }
```