# Show the output in an array of values

Tags: arrays, mongodb, project

Hello I have this query result

```
{
    sac: 1,
    sac_db: 0,
    kafka: 1,
    platform: 13700,
}
```

now I just want to show the values in an array, but I can't find how to do it:

```
[1,0,1,13700]
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706878/how-to-show-only-element-of-array-in-output

Comment: It is not the same, I have different values in an object (key:value) and I want to project in a single array with all the values in order

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done using `$map` and `$objectToArray`, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      results: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
              },
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  "$$this.k",
                  "_id"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          in: "$$this.v"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XY8BWcBdZG1)

Comment: Thank you with your answer I have obtained the result that I expected